# push data in an array using codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have user_sport_tbl,sport_tbl tables. in user_sport_tbl i have sport_id but not have sport name.Sport name is in sport_tbl.

i have a function of getUserSport() of Model.

my query :-

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('user_sport_tbl',array('username' => $username));
```

i want sport_name for every sport_id and want to merge sport_name in array.

my code :-

```
    public function getUserSport()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_sport_tbl',array('username' => $username));
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $item)
        {
            $query1 = $this->db->query("select sport_name from sport_tbl where sport_id=$item->sport_name order by sport_id limit 1");
            $sql1 = $query1->row();

            $data[] = array_push($item, $sql1->sport_name);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

my present return data:-

```
 [user_match_id] => 7 [sport_id] => 2 [match_id] => 3 [username] => admin
```

i want to add [sport_name] => cricket.

I want to return an array with sportname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this coding

```
public function getUserSport()
{
   $data = array();
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_sport_tbl',array('username' => $username));
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        foreach($query->result() as $key=>$item)
        {
            $query1 = $this->db->query("select sport_name from sport_tbl where sport_id=$item->sport_name order by sport_id limit 1");
            $sql1 = $query1->row();

            $item[$key]['sport_name']  = $sql1->sport_name;

            $data[] = $item;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have got this error:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/game/application/models/user_model.php on line 166

Comment: what is 166 line ?  result() replace to result_array(); and $item->sport_name replace to $item['sport_name']; then working fine

Comment: 166 line is :
$item[$key]['sport_name']  = $sql1->sport_name;

Comment: result() replace to result_array(); and $item->sport_name replace to $item['sport_name']; then working fine

Comment: i am getting this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/game/application/models/user_model.php on line 147

on Line 147 code:

$query1 = $this->db->query("select sport_name from sport_tbl where sport_id=$item['sport_name'] order by sport_id limit 1");

Comment: $query1 = $this->db->query("select sport_name from sport_tbl where sport_id=".$item['sport_name']." order by sport_id limit 1"); Use this coding

Comment: I am getting this output:

Array ( [user_match_id] => 7 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin ) Array ( [user_match_id] => 8 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin ) Array ( [user_match_id] => 8 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin => Array ( [sport_name] => Cricket ) )

Comment: But i want in this format
Array ( [user_match_id] => 7 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin [sport_name] => Cricket ) Array ( [user_match_id] => 8 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin [sport_name] => Soccer ) Array ( [user_match_id] => 8 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin [sport_name] => Tennis )

Comment: I want every array has sport_name , right now i got one sport_name and the end from your code

Comment: pls replace the sport_name to sportname, because already have the same name in array

Comment: Otherwise try this query     $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT user_sport_tbl.sport_name as user_sportname, sport_tbl.sport_name  as sport_sportname
        FROM user_sport_tbl 
        INNER JOIN sport_tbl 
        ON user_sport_tbl.sport_name = sport_tbl.sport_id
        WHERE user_sport_tbl.username = '".$username."' ORDER BY sport_tbl.sport_id LIMIT 1");

Comment: Now I got this result : -

Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_match_id] => 7 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin [0] => Array ( [sportname] => Cricket ) ) [1] => Array ( [user_match_id] => 8 [sport_name] => 2 [match_name] => 3 [username] => admin [1] => Array ( [sportname] => Cricket ) ) )

But How can i got this result in view using for each loop?

Comment: If you apply result_array() in second query, So only this result. Apply the old coding  $sql1 = $query1->row();         $item[$key]['sport_name']  = $sql1->sport_name;

Comment: pls use this coding, then working fine $result = $query->result_array();  foreach($result  as $key=>$item)
        {
            $query1 = $this->db->query("select sport_name from sport_tbl where sport_id=".$item['sport_name']." order by sport_id limit 1");
            $sql1 = $query1->row();

            $result[$key]['sportname']  = $sql1->sport_name;
        }  return $result;

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function getUserSport()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('user_sport_tbl',array('username' => $username));
    if(empty($query))
    {
        foreach($query->result_array() as $item)
        {
            $sportsId = $item[0]['sport_name'];
            $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT sport_name FROM sport_tbl WHERE sport_id = $sportsId ORDER BY sport_id LIMIT 1");
            $result = $query1->result_array();

            $data[] = array_push($item, $result[0]['sport_name']);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Or can do with join query too ***(Not tested. If any error fix it.
 or post the message her)***

```
public function getUserSport()
{
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT user_sport_tbl.sport_name, sport_tbl.sport_name
        FROM user_sport_tbl 
        INNER JOIN sport_tbl 
        ON user_sport_tbl.username = sport_tbl.sport_name
        WHERE user_sport_tbl.username = '$username' ORDER BY sport_tbl.sport_id LIMIT 1");
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: @ManishTiwari check this out

Comment: print_r($query->result_array()) and check